# How do you remove duplicate words in a text file using in python?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, parsing, duplicates

Here's the text from the file:

```
Amlodipine 5 MG / Hydrochlorothiazide 25 MG / Olmesartan medoxomil 40 MG Oral Tablet
aliskiren 150 MG / valsartan 160 MG Oral Tablet
aliskiren 300 MG / valsartan 320 MG Oral Tablet
azilsartan medoxomil 40 MG Oral Tablet
azilsartan medoxomil 80 MG Oral Tablet
azilsartan medoxomil 40 MG / Chlorthalidone 12.5 MG Oral Tablet
azilsartan medoxomil 40 MG / Chlorthalidone 25 MG Oral Tablet
```

I want the output like this:

```
Amlodipine 5 MG / Hydrochlorothiazide 25 MG / Olmesartan medoxomil 40 MG Oral Tablet
aliskiren 150 MG / valsartan 160 MG 
300 MG / 320 MG 
40 MG 
80 MG 
40 MG / Chlorthalidone 12.5 MG 
40 MG / 25 MG
```

Comment: this is a good question but you are asking us to write the code for you and again the question is not even clear what do you actually you just told us the input then the output

Comment: Before asking for help here, it's better to show your own efforts and explain why they haven't worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

text = '''Amlodipine 5 MG / Hydrochlorothiazide 25 MG / Olmesartan medoxomil 40 MG Oral Tablet aliskiren 150 MG / valsartan 160 MG Oral Tablet aliskiren 300 MG / valsartan 320 MG Oral Tablet azilsartan medoxomil 40 MG Oral Tablet azilsartan medoxomil 80 MG Oral Tablet azilsartan medoxomil 40 MG / Chlorthalidone 12.5 MG Oral Tablet azilsartan medoxomil 40 MG / Chlorthalidone 25 MG Oral Tablet'''

delimiter = ' / '
result = delimiter.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(text.split(delimiter)))
print(result)
```

The *str.split()* separates the text into separate entries.  The `OrderedDict.fromkeys()` eliminates duplicates while keeping the original ordering.  The *str.join()* recombines the separate entries into a single string using the original delimiter.

See [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [OrderedDict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), [fromkeys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys), and [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).